# ListBox within ListBox - Selection behavior

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

In a `List` I store several items with a header and sub items

```
_categories = new List<Category>();

Category cOne = new Category() { Header = "Category one" };
cOne.AddItem("Sub One");
cOne.AddItem("Sub Two");
cOne.AddItem("Sub Three");
_categories.Add(cOne);
```

In WPF I bind these items to a `ListBox`.

```
<ListBox x:Name="listbox">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}" />
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Subs}" Padding="10 0 0 0" />
      </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

What I now try but fail is to make only the items in the inner `ListBox` click-able, i.e. to avoid:

[image]

If I set `TextBlock.IsEnabled` or `TextBlock.IsHitTestVisible` to false nothing changes. If the `StackPanel's` properties are set to false the inner `ListBox` isn't click-able any more but interestingly the `TextBlock` still is. And the outer `ListBox's` properties prevents to click anything at all.

The behavior is identical if the outer `ListBox` is a `ListView` instead.

I haven't figured out yet what I need to change to make sure that only the items in the inner list are enabled. Any ideas?

Comment: @HighCore Thanks for the comment. In the end, this does have the same effect as using IsEnabled.

Comment: Have you tried using an `ItemsControl` for the outer list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is no need to select the items in the outer `ListBox` whatsoever, do not use a `ListBox` - use an `ItemsControl` instead:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="itemsControl">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}" />
                <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Subs}" Padding="10 0 0 0" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl >
```

Comment: Well, at first I thought you were right but it doesn't change anything at all.

Comment: You probably meant `ItemsControl`. `ListView` is a descendent of `Selector`, so it's meant for selecting items.

Comment: @nikie you are right of course. I got that messed up. Thanks for pointing that out! Note to myself: Think - Think again - Write.